# Atom editorでvimでコマンドを実行したときのようなバッファを実現する

Tags: vim, atom-editor

vimで`:! echo hello`のようにコマンドを実行するとvimの一時的に作られたBufferに結果が表示されます

これと同じようなことをatomで実現できないのでしょうか?
TextEditorとTextBufferを使うのだと思うのですが、どうすればいいのかわかりません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ググったらこんなのがありました。
最新版パッケージをインストールして使います。

https://atom.io/packages/run-command